# Ray-Capsule intersection

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, intersection

I have a capsule defined by two points `A` and `B` and radius `r`. The ray is defined by equation: `X = O + D*t`. Now I need to get `t` for all (0-2) intersection points.

One possible solution would be to calculate intersection with spheres at `A` and `B` and intersections with cylinder. Then because capsule is convex I would just take minimum and maximum of all resulting `t` values.

But as [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume) states, capsule intersection test should be even simpler than cylinder intersection test. Could somebody point me to an efficient capsule-ray intersection algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test whether a capsule intersects a ray line just test distance between the line segment crossing points `A` and `B` and the ray line. If the distance is smaller than radius `r` then there are two intersecting points, if is equal there is one touching point.

To calculate intersection do as you described.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is completely thought through. One can check minimum distance between two lines but how do you do this for a segment and a ray?

Comment: The problem here is that computing the distance between two segments is nearly as complex as doing the real ray/capsule intersection, and you still need that second part to get the intersection points.

Answer (score 2):

using the closest point between the ray and segment doesn't work in all circumstances if the ray is within the radius of the capsule and roughly parallel/shallow angle to the capsule then it can result in the collision being computed a the other end of the capsule

Comment: Probably more a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Wikipedia means intersection of two capsules, it indeed seems to be simpler that intersection of two cylinders.

I would search for intersection points just as you described...